# Change Java Home when building with gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

```
Working Directory: ...
Gradle user home: ...
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 6.8
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: build
```

I want to change Java Home to a JDK 16, how do I do this???

This is in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phew... I had a same problem with you.
Here is how I solve it:

1. Project right mouse click -> Run As -> Run configurations
2. [Run Configurations] Gradle Task -> {project.name} - bootwhatever click
   -> in right side click tab [Project Settings]
3. [Project settings] check 'Override project settings'
   in [Advanced Options]
   Set Gradle user home, and Java home you want
4. button 'Run' click

** my eclipse
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902